# Having difficulties converting SQL query to Laravel builder

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am trying to convert the following query to laravels using query builder but having some issue with group by clause and sum aggregated functions

```
SELECT code, SUM(quantity) as quantity, SUM(sale_price) as price
FROM `orders` o
GROUP By code
```

I have tried this, this is what I have after so many desperate tries.

```
$args['orders'] = DB::table('orders')
->havingRaw('sum(sale_price)')
->havingRaw('code')
->where([ 'shop_id' => $shop_id ])
->groupBy('code')
->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
$args['orders'] = DB::table('orders')
->where('shop_id', '=', $shop_id)
->select('code', DB::raw('sum(quantity) as quantity, sum(sale_price) as price'))
->groupBy('code')
->get();
```

Order by

```
$args['orders'] = DB::table('orders')
->where('shop_id', '=', $shop_id)
->select('code', DB::raw('sum(quantity) as quantity, sum(sale_price) as price'))
->groupBy('code')
->orderBy('quantity')
->get();
```

Or try

```
->orderByRaw('sum(quantity)')
```

Comment: How would I add order_by column in this?

Comment: Nah, order_by is actually a column which will be joined to another table.

Comment: Then simply use `tablename.column` inside of `orderBy()`

Comment: SELECT code, order_by, SUM(quantity) as quantity, SUM(sale_price) as price FROM `orders` o GROUP By code

Comment: Then simply add `->orderBy('order_by')` to the query before `get()`

Comment: Nah, I want to select this column

Comment: Fixed it, I was not putting it in groupby, final result:

        $args['orders'] = DB::table('orders')
        ->where([ 'shop_id' => $shop_id ])
        ->select('code', DB::raw('sum(quantity) as quantity, sum(sale_price) as price, order_by'))
        ->groupBy('code', 'order_by')
        ->get();

Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136856/discussion-between-eddythedove-and-waleed).